# Triangle inequality problem2

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The quantity $|x-y|$ is called the distance between $x$ and $y$ vectors. Prove and interpret geometrically the "triangle inequality": $|z-x| \le |z-y|+|y-x|$.

I tried to rewrite this equation in Sums: $\sum_{i=1}^n (z_i -x_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (z_i-y_i)^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-x_i)^2 +2*\sum_{i=1}^n(z_i-y_i)(y_i-x_i) $

Then I just simplified it and the result I got was:  $0\le0$, then I stuck here.

Comment: You should discuss the relative value of $x$, $y$ and $z$ and verify the inequality for all cases.

Comment: What is the square of the RHS in the original inequality?

Comment: For the proof, try https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1762283/from-cosine-formula-between-two-vectors-to-schwarz-inequality-and-triangle-inequ

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to rewrite the equation in sums. Here is an easier approach. 
Set $a=z-y$ and $b=y-x$. Now what you need to proof is equivalent to $|a+b|\le|a|+|b|$.  
 Squaring both sides gives $|a+b|^2 \le |a|^2+2|a||b|+|b|^2  <=> (a+b)^2 \le a^2+2|a||b|+b^2 <=> a^2+2ab+b^2 \le a^2+2|a||b|+b^2 <=> 2ab \le 2|a||b| <=> ab \le |a||b| \space\ $ (here ab holds for the scalar product of $a$ and $b$). 
The last inequality is obvious since $ab=|a||b|cos\gamma$ where $\gamma$ is the angle between $a$and $b$. **The geometrical interpretation is easy indeed. It means that in a triangle (possibly degenerated)  the sum of lengths of two sides is always greater or equal to the length of the third one.**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the folowing figure.
[image: vectors x,y,z]